# SSRS chart does not show

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am writing a small sales status report in SSRS. The top has monthly and daily summaries in four small tables. I added a couple charts, and then I added a pie chart. It looked great. I have never added map, so I tried that (using local state data that came with SSRS). Unfortunately, the map didn't show up even though the report gives no errors or warnings.

I deleted the map, but the pie chart still did not show. I deleted the pie chart and recreated it, but it still does not show either in Preview or Run. I deployed it to test it there, and it builds and deploys without error, but does not show in either Chrome or IE10.

What is wrong? The visibility is set to Show, and I verified there are no filters. What am I overlooking? This is the entire chart that is not showing. I have not directly edited any of the XML code--I have only edited through the Design view.

```
      <Chart Name="Chart3">
        <ChartCategoryHierarchy>
          <ChartMembers>
            <ChartMember>
              <Group Name="Chart3_CategoryGroup">
                <GroupExpressions>
                  <GroupExpression>=Fields!Sales_Person.Value</GroupExpression>
                </GroupExpressions>
              </Group>
              <SortExpressions>
                <SortExpression>
                  <Value>=Fields!Sales_Person.Value</Value>
                </SortExpression>
              </SortExpressions>
              <Label>=Fields!Sales_Person.Value</Label>
            </ChartMember>
          </ChartMembers>
        </ChartCategoryHierarchy>
        <ChartSeriesHierarchy>
          <ChartMembers>
            <ChartMember>
              <Label>SO Sales Amt</Label>
            </ChartMember>
          </ChartMembers>
        </ChartSeriesHierarchy>
        <ChartData>
          <ChartSeriesCollection>
            <ChartSeries Name="SO_Sales_Amt">
              <ChartDataPoints>
                <ChartDataPoint>
                  <ChartDataPointValues>
                    <Y>=Sum(Fields!SO_Sales_Amt.Value)</Y>
                  </ChartDataPointValues>
                  <ChartDataLabel>
                    <Style />
                  </ChartDataLabel>
                  <Style />
                  <ChartMarker>
                    <Style />
                  </ChartMarker>
                  <DataElementOutput>Output</DataElementOutput>
                </ChartDataPoint>
              </ChartDataPoints>
              <Type>Shape</Type>
              <Style />
              <ChartEmptyPoints>
                <Style />
                <ChartMarker>
                  <Style />
                </ChartMarker>
                <ChartDataLabel>
                  <Style />
                </ChartDataLabel>
              </ChartEmptyPoints>
              <ValueAxisName>Primary</ValueAxisName>
              <CategoryAxisName>Primary</CategoryAxisName>
              <ChartSmartLabel>
                <CalloutLineColor>Black</CalloutLineColor>
                <MinMovingDistance>0pt</MinMovingDistance>
              </ChartSmartLabel>
            </ChartSeries>
          </ChartSeriesCollection>
        </ChartData>
        <ChartAreas>
          <ChartArea Name="Default">
            <ChartCategoryAxes>
              <ChartAxis Name="Primary">
                <Style>
                  <FontSize>8pt</FontSize>
                </Style>
                <ChartAxisTitle>
                  <Caption>Axis Title</Caption>
                  <Style>
                    <FontSize>8pt</FontSize>
                  </Style>
                </ChartAxisTitle>
                <ChartMajorGridLines>
                  <Enabled>False</Enabled>
                  <Style>
                    <Border>
                      <Color>Gainsboro</Color>
                    </Border>
                  </Style>
                </ChartMajorGridLines>
                <ChartMinorGridLines>
                  <Style>
                    <Border>
                      <Color>Gainsboro</Color>
                      <Style>Dotted</Style>
                    </Border>
                  </Style>
                </ChartMinorGridLines>
                <ChartMinorTickMarks>
                  <Length>0.5</Length>
                </ChartMinorTickMarks>
                <CrossAt>NaN</CrossAt>
                <Minimum>NaN</Minimum>
                <Maximum>NaN</Maximum>
                <ChartAxisScaleBreak>
                  <Style />
                </ChartAxisScaleBreak>
              </ChartAxis>
              <ChartAxis Name="Secondary">
                <Style>
                  <FontSize>8pt</FontSize>
                </Style>
                <ChartAxisTitle>
                  <Caption>Axis Title</Caption>
                  <Style>
                    <FontSize>8pt</FontSize>
                  </Style>
                </ChartAxisTitle>
                <ChartMajorGridLines>
                  <Enabled>False</Enabled>
                  <Style>
                    <Border>
                      <Color>Gainsboro</Color>
                    </Border>
                  </Style>
                </ChartMajorGridLines>
                <ChartMinorGridLines>
                  <Style>
                    <Border>
                      <Color>Gainsboro</Color>
                      <Style>Dotted</Style>
                    </Border>
                  </Style>
                </ChartMinorGridLines>
                <ChartMinorTickMarks>
                  <Length>0.5</Length>
                </ChartMinorTickMarks>
                <CrossAt>NaN</CrossAt>
                <Location>Opposite</Location>
                <Minimum>NaN</Minimum>
                <Maximum>NaN</Maximum>
                <ChartAxisScaleBreak>
                  <Style />
                </ChartAxisScaleBreak>
              </ChartAxis>
            </ChartCategoryAxes>
            <ChartValueAxes>
              <ChartAxis Name="Primary">
                <Style>
                  <FontSize>8pt</FontSize>
                </Style>
                <ChartAxisTitle>
                  <Caption>Axis Title</Caption>
                  <Style>
                    <FontSize>8pt</FontSize>
                  </Style>
                </ChartAxisTitle>
                <ChartMajorGridLines>
                  <Style>
                    <Border>
                      <Color>Gainsboro</Color>
                    </Border>
                  </Style>
                </ChartMajorGridLines>
                <ChartMinorGridLines>
                  <Style>
                    <Border>
                      <Color>Gainsboro</Color>
                      <Style>Dotted</Style>
                    </Border>
                  </Style>
                </ChartMinorGridLines>
                <ChartMinorTickMarks>
                  <Length>0.5</Length>
                </ChartMinorTickMarks>
                <CrossAt>NaN</CrossAt>
                <Minimum>NaN</Minimum>
                <Maximum>NaN</Maximum>
                <ChartAxisScaleBreak>
                  <Style />
                </ChartAxisScaleBreak>
              </ChartAxis>
              <ChartAxis Name="Secondary">
                <Style>
                  <FontSize>8pt</FontSize>
                </Style>
                <ChartAxisTitle>
                  <Caption>Axis Title</Caption>
                  <Style>
                    <FontSize>8pt</FontSize>
                  </Style>
                </ChartAxisTitle>
                <ChartMajorGridLines>
                  <Style>
                    <Border>
                      <Color>Gainsboro</Color>
                    </Border>
                  </Style>
                </ChartMajorGridLines>
                <ChartMinorGridLines>
                  <Style>
                    <Border>
                      <Color>Gainsboro</Color>
                      <Style>Dotted</Style>
                    </Border>
                  </Style>
                </ChartMinorGridLines>
                <ChartMinorTickMarks>
                  <Length>0.5</Length>
                </ChartMinorTickMarks>
                <CrossAt>NaN</CrossAt>
                <Location>Opposite</Location>
                <Minimum>NaN</Minimum>
                <Maximum>NaN</Maximum>
                <ChartAxisScaleBreak>
                  <Style />
                </ChartAxisScaleBreak>
              </ChartAxis>
            </ChartValueAxes>
            <Style>
              <BackgroundGradientType>None</BackgroundGradientType>
            </Style>
          </ChartArea>
        </ChartAreas>
        <ChartLegends>
          <ChartLegend Name="Default">
            <Style>
              <BackgroundGradientType>None</BackgroundGradientType>
              <FontSize>8pt</FontSize>
            </Style>
            <ChartLegendTitle>
              <Caption />
              <Style>
                <FontSize>8pt</FontSize>
                <FontWeight>Bold</FontWeight>
                <TextAlign>Center</TextAlign>
              </Style>
            </ChartLegendTitle>
            <HeaderSeparatorColor>Black</HeaderSeparatorColor>
            <ColumnSeparatorColor>Black</ColumnSeparatorColor>
          </ChartLegend>
        </ChartLegends>
        <ChartTitles>
          <ChartTitle Name="Default">
            <Caption>Sales Breakdown</Caption>
            <Style>
              <BackgroundGradientType>None</BackgroundGradientType>
              <FontWeight>Bold</FontWeight>
              <TextAlign>General</TextAlign>
              <VerticalAlign>Top</VerticalAlign>
            </Style>
            <Position>TopLeft</Position>
          </ChartTitle>
        </ChartTitles>
        <Palette>BrightPastel</Palette>
        <ChartBorderSkin>
          <Style>
            <BackgroundColor>Gray</BackgroundColor>
            <BackgroundGradientType>None</BackgroundGradientType>
            <Color>White</Color>
          </Style>
        </ChartBorderSkin>
        <ChartNoDataMessage Name="NoDataMessage">
          <Caption>No Data Available</Caption>
          <Style>
            <BackgroundGradientType>None</BackgroundGradientType>
            <TextAlign>General</TextAlign>
            <VerticalAlign>Top</VerticalAlign>
          </Style>
        </ChartNoDataMessage>
        <DataSetName>SalesHistory</DataSetName>
        <Top>9.06125in</Top>
        <Height>3.15625in</Height>
        <Width>3.97917in</Width>
        <ZIndex>27</ZIndex>
        <Style>
          <Border>
            <Color>LightGrey</Color>
            <Style>Solid</Style>
          </Border>
          <BackgroundColor>White</BackgroundColor>
          <BackgroundGradientType>None</BackgroundGradientType>
        </Style>
      </Chart>
```

Comment: Can you clarify please - you said you "added a pie chart" and it "looked great". Then you added and deleted a map. Now the pie chart does not display. Did the pie chart initially display and now it does not display?

Comment: Yes, the pie chart displayed, then I added the map, but the map did not display. Or the pie chart. So I removed them both and tried recreating them. 

The problem is that they were split onto a second page. What I want is one long webpage report without any page breaks. I've not seen a report broken up like this before, so I missed the "1 of 2 >" in the ribbon. Now I can see both the pie chart and map! 

Except I don't know why there is a page break. I didn't insert one.

Comment: Try increasing the page size - in the Properties window, select "Report" and adjust the PageSize (for export to PDF etc) and/or InteractiveSize (this governs how paging works when displayed in the browser).